# auto reconnect in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, reconnect

:D Hi there

I have installed jboss-as-7.1.1.Final for my webapp.

Its running normally for every activity except one thing.
When ms sql server services was restarted or stopped a while, my jboss wouldn't rebuild the connection to datasource automatically.

I must restarting jboss manually, so it can rebuild the connection again.

What i want is jboss autoreconnecting when that problem happen again.
Below is my datacource config, could you tell me please what i am miss?

```
....
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MsSqlDS" pool-name="MsSqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
   <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dummy</connection-url>
   <driver>sqlserver2008</driver>
   <pool>
          <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
          <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
          <prefill>false</prefill>
          <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
          <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
   </pool>
   <security>
          <user-name>sa</user-name>
          <password>*******</password>
   </security>
   <validation>
          <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
   </validation>
</datasource>
....
```

note :
i have try this

```
<validation> 
   <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
</validation>
```

based on [Is there any way to have the JBoss connection pool reconnect to Oracle when connections go bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128527/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-jboss-connection-pool-reconnect-to-oracle-when-conn)

but still not work for me

Thanks & Regards

Newbie

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549894/jboss-reconnecting-on-connection-time-out

Comment: thanks for reply Federico,


i think that link is the correct answer, cause in the other forums suggesting that too.
Have added that snippet before, but still not working for me :(

Comment: always getting error "The connection is closed"

Comment: Try setting `use-ccm="true"` in the datasource configuration

Comment: Sorry my bad, the snippet in that link was work. The problem was come from me. I didn't closing the connection properly in my app. Thanks Federico

Comment: Please refer to this [link][1] where I have put my answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957462/jboss-auto-reconnect-with-database-when-database-is-restarted-disconnect/27905194#27905194